# Repeating events

Tags: c#, events

is there a way to shoot an event in C# continuously every time period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the `DispatcherTimer` class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx

You can set some time period for the `DispatcherTimer` to fire it's `tick` event -- either do what you want here, or in the handler for the `tick` event, fire off your event.

Answer (score 0):

Timers?

Google found me these link.

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/sample_chapter/article.php/c7763

Unless you have form application then you may want to use the timer in the form namespace.  This way you will not have to worry executing control modifications on a non-main thread.

(I only get one hyperlink so google for C# timers)